# Built-in post beautifier for automatic fix of basic typographical errors

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-improvement, typographical-error, writing-style

I do not know if many people care about brand/technology names, typography and typesetting conventions, but my eyes bleed everytime I see a post containing this...

> Html, css, Javascript, Jquery, json, Php, mySQL, postgresql, VIM, intellij, visual studio

... instead of this:

> HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, JSON, PHP, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Vim, IntelliJ, Visual Studio

Of course, I am not talking about tags which have to be lowercase for technical reasons. Tags are great as they are. What I am saying is that it is important to respect official names in the content of a post. Vim is a text editor, whereas VIM is a French company specialized in ventilation. Sometimes case matters, and generally, it improves readability when it is used properly.

Moreover, question titles that do not begin with a capital letter look terrible. A question like this...

> how to send ajax requests using javascript and xmlhttprequest

... sends a really bad signal in terms of quality. This is much better:

> How to send AJAX requests using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest?

**My question comes here:** would it be possible to implement a built-in post beautifier that parses the textual content (out of code snippets) on validation, replaces each occurrence of badly written names with their correct typography, and forces uppercase for the first letter in a question title?

We could also imagine name suggestions in the editor. For example, if the user types "javasc", the system should be able to suggest "JavaScript" on the fly (like mentions with `@` in comments). A leading capital letter should be proposed (or imposed) too when the appropriate input field has focus.

Comment: This would be awesome, but it would be incredibly difficult to implement.

Comment: MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145920/179419 given the number of times this has been asked (see linked questions) I juat don't think it's a priority for SE, understandably.

Comment: I have [a list](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2017-05-16.html)... (99% actually observed in the wild)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Your list is impressive... How did you extract all this data?

Answer (score 5):

One immediate practical problem with this is that many people post their code outside of code blocks as plain text. The mechanism you're proposing would change the casing of perfectly valid identifiers such as `html`, `css`, which could break the code.

Of course, people *should* post code in code blocks, but the fact of the matter is that new (and sometimes not-so-new) user get this wrong.

Additionally, sometimes people put error messages inside quote blocks rather than code blocks. This is often perfectly valid and a stylistic choice, but it would also break things.

So aside from whether such an auto-correct mechanism is *desirable*, it is certainly not very *practical* and will probably introduce more problem than it solves (I've undoubtedly missed several scenarios where this may cause problems).

> forces uppercase for the first letter in a question title?

What if my question title starts with jQuery? :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I totally agree with your first two paragraphs. This is probably the main problem that would make this feature difficult to implement. About error messages in quote blocks, I do this myself. But quote blocks could be ignored by the parser, just like code blocks. "*What if my question title starts with jQuery?*" I considered this point before posting this question and I came to the conclusion that a leading capital letter could be a necessary evil. I flagged so many poorly written questions these days that I try to find anything that could mitigate this phenomenon...

Comment: By the way, what do you think about the idea presented in the last paragraph of my question? This is a less coercive and more suggestive way to approach the same problem...

Comment: Seems a lot of effort to fix a very minor issue @Badacadabra; personally I couldn't care less if a user uses "html" or "HTML". In both cases the intended meaning is unambiguously clear.

Comment: Well... Given the downvotes, it seems that most people agree with you. I can understand this point of view, of course. But I truly think typesetting conventions are underrated nowadays. They are constantly violated on the Web and this is a real problem. And I swear, "html" is really painful for my eyes. I am sure many designers and linguists would share this opinion. :)

Comment: The problem is that they're exactly that @Badacadabra: conventions :-) "HTML" is in no way objectively better than "html". Language is defined by its usage, not a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but I think we always need conventions somewhere. English or French languages are full of conventions. Without conventions, we would not be able to communicate. It is also true in development: a codebase without conventions is hard to read, understand and maintain. ;)